# React: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, syntax, react-props

I have the following HTML to render using React:

```
      <a
        style='background-color:black;color:white;text-decoration:none;padding:4px 6px;font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "San Francisco", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Ubuntu, Roboto, Noto, "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;line-height:1;display:inline-block;border-radius:3px'
        href= //...
        target='_blank'
        rel='noopener noreferrer'
        className='credit-box-abs'
      >
        <span style='display:inline-block;padding:2px 3px;font-size:11px'>
          <i className='fas fa-camera-retro'></i>
        </span>
        <span style='display:inline-block;padding:2px 3px'>Photographer name</span>
      </a>
```

When I try to compile, I get the following warnings about each `style`:

```
Style prop value must be an object
```

And the error:

```
The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string.
```

The suggested solution from the compiler, as well as online, states:

```
<div style={{ styleAttribute: 'whatever', ... }}>
```

So I've tried the following:

```
      <a
        style={{background-color:'black';color:'white';text-decoration:'none';padding:'4px 6px';font-family:'-apple-system , BlinkMacSystemFont, \"San Francisco\", \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Ubuntu, Roboto, Noto, \"Segoe UI\", Arial, sans-serif ';font-size:'8px';font-weight:'bold';line-height:'1';display:'inline-block';border-radius:'3px'}}
        href= //...
        target='_blank'
        rel='noopener noreferrer'
        className='credit-box-abs'
      >
        <span style='display:inline-block;padding:2px 3px;font-size:11px'>
          <i className='fas fa-camera-retro'></i>
        </span>
        <span style='display:inline-block;padding:2px 3px'>Photographer name</span>
      </a>
```

But the syntax is not correct. Am I supposed to wrap all values of each attribute in `''`? In particular, the syntax for `background-color: 'black'` is giving redlines under, as well as redline under my closing `</a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

`background-color` is a css property, for the same JS property name is `backgroundColor`, so if you try `{backgroundColor: 'black'}`, that should work.

For more CSS and their respective JS properties check out [Common CSS Properties Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference)